# Vuejs.org Docs color theme for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone know what color theme is used for the code examples in the documentation at [Vuejs.org Docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcyQ4.png)) ?
Is there a similar color theme for Visual Studio Code ?
I would be very grateful for your help.

Update:
An unofficial version of the VitePress theme appeared in the VS Marketplace:
[VitePress Theme (unofficial) by Jan Fröhlic](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zanfee.theme-vitepress)

Answer (score 0):

the **VitePress** theme is used for the official Vue documentation at `vuejs.org.`  and it is licensed by MIT. See this [link](https://github.com/vuejs/theme)